# ROCAUC = average sensitivity across all thresholds according to IEEE TPAMI, yet my calculations show otherwise

Tags: r, machine-learning, roc, auc, sensitivity-specificity

[Carrington et al (2023)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9693294) make the claim that area under the receiver-operator characteristic curve is equal to the average sensitivity across all thresholds, and similarly for specificity (section 3), citing a book by Zhou, McClish, and Obuchowski (2002).

> Two other less commonly known interpretations of the AUC are that AUC equals average sensitivity across all thresholds, and AUC equals average specificity across all thresholds.

I had never heard this and wrote a simulation to check it out. The results are about the same if the sample size `N` is increased to at least a million and the number of repetitions `R` to at least ten-thousand.

```r
library(pROC)
set.seed(2024)
N <- 1000
R <- 1000
aucs <- senss <- specs <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  
  # Simulate some data
  #
  p <- rbeta(N, 1, 1)
  y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)
  
  # Calculate the ROC curve
  #
  my_roc <- pROC::roc(y, p)
  
  # Save the area under the ROC curve
  #
  aucs[i] <- my_roc$auc
  
  # Save the mean sensitivity and mean specificity values
  #
  senss[i] <- mean(my_roc$sensitivities)
  specs[i] <- mean(my_roc$specificities)
}

# Are all three equal?
#
summary(aucs - senss)
summary(aucs - specs)
summary(senss - specs)
```

The `summary` calls show that the AUC always differs (rather considerably) from both the average sensitivity and the average specificity. Further, the average sensitivity and average specificity are not even equal.

It appears that the claim in the article is, then, incorrect. Is there something weird about how `pROC` does the calculations? Is there some narrower sense in which the claim would be correct? (Did I just write code with a bug?)

**REFERENCES**

Carrington, André M., et al. "Deep ROC analysis and AUC as balanced average accuracy, for improved classifier selection, audit and explanation." IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence 45.1 (2022): 329-341.

X.-H. Zhou, D. K. McClish, and N. A. Obuchowski, "Statistical
Methods in Diagnostic Medicine." Hoboken, NJ, USA: Wiley, 2002.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is decidedly not my area of expertise so I'll refrain from interpreting anything, and I apologize if I only say trivial things. Since the ROC curve is given plotting sensitivity against specificity at various threshold values, the area under the curve is the average of both sensitivity and specificity (over all values of the other) in the sense that the integral of a function is just the "average" of that function.

Moreover, the computed `my_roc$specificities` and `my_roc$sensitivities` are not evenly spaced so if you want to compute the average of the specificity over all sensitivities in your simulation, you will need to weigh each specificity by "how large" the band of sensitivities that specificity corresponds to is. For example, in the below picture (at `N = 100` for visual clairity), the sensitivity computed in the red circle is given for a large band of specificity compared to the black circle, but `mean(my_roc$specificities)` discards that. [image: ROC plot]

Once we take this into account, everything seems to work out alright. The following code gives all three bottom differences as basically equal, as expected: this weighted average is identical to a Riemann sum, e.g.

```
senss[i] <- weighted.mean(my_roc$sensitivities[1:N],
                            diff(my_roc$specificities))
```

and

```
  senss[i] <- sum(my_roc$sensitivities[1:N] * diff(my_roc$specificities))
```

are exactly the same. So I think the issue is how one interprets/computes the phrase "average across all thresholds."

```
library(pROC)
set.seed(2024)
N <- 1000
R <- 1000
aucs <- senss <- specs <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  # Simulate some data
  p <- rbeta(N, 1, 1)
  y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)

  # Calculate the ROC curve
  my_roc <- pROC::roc(y, p)

  # Save the area under the ROC curve
  #
  aucs[i] <- my_roc$auc

  # Save the mean sensitivity and mean specificity values
  senss[i] <- weighted.mean(my_roc$sensitivities[1:N],
                            diff(my_roc$specificities))
  specs[i] <- weighted.mean(my_roc$specificities[1:N],
                            diff(my_roc$sensitivities))
}

# Are all three equal?
#
summary(aucs - senss)
summary(aucs - specs)
summary(senss - specs)

}

# Are all three equal?
#
summary(aucs - senss)
summary(aucs - specs)
summary(senss - specs)
```

I get the following results.

```
> summary(aucs - senss)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0       0       0       0       0       0 
> summary(aucs - specs)
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-1.354e-14 -1.665e-15  3.331e-16  4.714e-16  2.776e-15  1.432e-14 
> summary(senss - specs)
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-1.354e-14 -1.665e-15  3.331e-16  4.714e-16  2.776e-15  1.432e-14
```